# Screenshot testing and Gitlab

Tags: android, testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci, screenshot

I try to enable the screenshot feature for Gitlab.
I don't know if this feature already available (14.4 version used).
In the documentation, they say that added then removed but not sur:https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/unit_test_reports.html#view-junit-screenshots-on-gitlab

Any information about that ?

Thanks

Comment: This feature was added in GitLab v13, so you should be good to go. The "feature flag" was removed, which is the ability to enable/disable this feature.

Comment: so by default is enabled for my version 14.4 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I have added the attachment in my report but I don't see any attchment displayed in gitlab in pipeline, any ideai ? : <testcase name="***" classname="****" time="0.355">
<system-out>[[ATTACHMENT|/path to screenshot]]</system-out>
<system-out>[[ATTACHMENT|/path to screenshot]]</system-out>
</testcase>

Comment: Can you show us your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as well as your junit config (in `pom.xml`, `build.xml`, or `build.gradle`).